# Impute NA values in column such that column sum and reference value is minimized in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R as below:

```
structure(list(Sales = c(1, 0, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 0, 2, 2), Txn_count = c(1, 
0, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 1), VPP = c(1, NaN, 4, 2, 2, 1.5, 3, 
NaN, 2, 2), prob = c(0.99, 0.81, 0.7, 0.8, 0.47, 0.59, 0.75, 
0.99, 0.53, 0.72), row_Sales = c(0.99, NaN, 2.8, 1.6, 0.94, 0.885, 
2.25, NaN, 1.06, 1.44)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Column VPP (Value per purchase) is calculated as Sales/Transaction for each row.

I have **sales_actual_vpp** calculated as

```
sum(probabilities)*[sum(sales)/sum(transaction)]
```

i.e.

```
sum(column D)*[sum(column A)/sum(column B)]
```

This gives value as **15.435**

Now, I want to impute NA values in column `row_Sales` such that difference between `sales_actual_vpp`  and `sum(column row_Sales)` after imputation is minimized. **Note that all NA values will be replaced by same value so that difference is still minimum**

How can I achieve this in R using solver ?

Comment: Set first NA to sales_actual_vpp - sum(row_Sales), other NAs to 0.  This solves your problem as you described it: the diffeerence between sales_actual_vpp and sum(row_Sales) becomes 0. If you want something else, be specific.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I have edited my question and highlighted the necessary condition in bold. I need to replace all NA values by this same value  such that difference is still minimized

Comment: Using R, (not Excel), I get __15.435__ for __sales_actual_vpp__. Can you double check?

Comment: Yes Edward, my mistake. I have corrected it.

Comment: Then you should set all NAs to (sales_actual_vpp - sum(row_Sales)) / number_of_NAs.   Does it solve your problem?